# Reload tabbarviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, view, tabbar

i have a tabbar view controller and I know with a navaigation controller you can reload the application so updates are shown. Is this possible with a tabbar view controller? I basically want it to refresh the screen when i click back into the tab instead of having to rotate the screen to get the new updates to show.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method `didSelectViewController:` and call  the selected viewController's `loadView:` or whatever method you use to load/update the view you want to refresh (maybe `viewWillAppear:` or similar as well).